# How do you remove Google Apps Directory information using the Directory API in the Admin SDK?

Tags: python, rest, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am using the Google Admin SDK, specifically the Directory API to change information for users' directory information in my organization. I am attempting to write a simple utility application in Python using Py library provided by Google. Adding and modifying information for the user seems to work just fine, the problem I run into is when I am trying to remove various pieces of information.

For example, the function I have to add an "organization" to the user with various attributes is:

```
def setOrgAttr(userKey, org, attr, value):

    global http, directory
    user = directory.users().get(userKey=userKey).execute(http=http)
    if u'organizations' in user:
        for orgIn in user[u'organizations']:
            if orgIn[u'name'] == org:
            orgIn[attr] = value
            else:
                user[u'organizations'].append({u'name':org,attr:value})
    else:
        user[u'organizations'] = [{u'name':org,attr:value}]

    directory.users().update(userKey=userKey,body=user).execute(http=http)
```

This works great, but removing doesn't work so well. I've tried using both `PUT` and `PATCH` methods as displayed on their API reference page https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/#Users but neither seem to work. I also attempted to just send the modified JSON vs. the entire user object, neither works. Here is my remove function:

```
def deleteOrg(userKey, org):

    global http, directory
    user = directory.users().get(userKey=userKey).execute(http=http)
    for (i, orgIn) in enumerate(user[u'organizations']):
        if orgIn[u'name'] == org:
            user[u'organizations'].pop(i)

    directory.users().patch(userKey=userKey,body=user).execute(http=http)
```

Lastly, to see everything in context here is a Gist that shows me entire app at this point.

https://gist.github.com/twhitney11/5f431c958aa822dc5ea5

I should note that debugging the request does show I am removing the organization from the JSON object before I send it to their API.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to:

```
modified_user = directory.users().patch(userKey=userKey,body=user).execute(http=http)
```

and see what modified_user['organizations'] looks like. Change to user's rich profile information (like organization) may take 4 hours or more to be reflected in the Gmail Contacts interface.

Comment: When I was debugging I tried:

`pprint.pprint(user)` 

and the body was what I expected, with the organization gone, then I did:

`pprint.pprint(directory.users().patch(userKey=userKey,body=user).execute(http=http))` 

and it wasn't what I expected, e.g. the organization was still there. This was 24 hours ago, and the organization is still there. When I use the `patch` method should I be sending the entire user object or only the empty organizations list?